# Linking an OS abstraction into a static library using CMake, but OS abstraction remains undefined in library?

Tags: c, cmake, static-libraries, static-linking

I have a simple project (for Zephyr RTOS, but I think my question is generic)

```
│   CMakeLists.txt
│   prj.conf
│   README.rst
│   sample.yaml
│
└───src
    │   lib_os_glue.c
    │   main.c
    │
    └───lib
            lib.c
            lib.h
            lib_os_glue.h
```

The idea is that the `lib` folder becomes a static library that can use Zephyr kernel calls. Hence I would like to compile those kernel calls into an OS glue layer, so that the library is independent of it.

Currently the project builds and can run, but in the resulting `liblib.a` I see that the `lib_os*` calls are undefined. (e.g. `UND lib_os_msleep` in the `readelf -aW liblib.a` output.

The CMakeLists.txt:

```
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20.0)

find_package(Zephyr REQUIRED HINTS $ENV{ZEPHYR_BASE})
project(hello_world)

target_sources(app PRIVATE src/main.c)
target_sources(app PRIVATE src/lib_os_glue.c)

add_library(lib STATIC src/lib/lib.c)
target_include_directories(lib PUBLIC src/lib)

target_link_libraries(app PRIVATE lib)
```

### The rest of the files

main.c:

```
#include <zephyr.h>
#include <sys/printk.h>

#include "lib.h"

void main(void)
{
  for (;;)
  {
    printk("Hello World! %s\n", CONFIG_BOARD);
    lib_msleep(1000);
  }
}
```

lib_os_glue.h:

```
#ifndef LIB_OS_GLUE_H
#define LIB_OS_GLUE_H

#include <stdint.h>

void lib_os_msleep (uint32_t ms_to_sleep);

#endif // LIB_OS_GLUE_H
```

lib_os_glue.c:

```
#include "lib_os_glue.h"

#include <stdint.h>
#include <zephyr.h>

void lib_os_msleep (uint32_t ms_to_sleep)
{
  k_msleep(ms_to_sleep);
}
```

lib/lib.h:

```
#ifndef LIB_H
#define LIB_H

#include <stdint.h>

void lib_msleep (uint32_t ms_to_sleep);

#endif // LIB_H
```

lib/lib.c:

```
#include "lib.h"
#include "lib_os_glue.h"

#include <stdint.h>

void lib_msleep (uint32_t ms_to_sleep)
{
  lib_os_msleep(ms_to_sleep);
}
```

---

I hope I'm close but I'm just not seeing the final step(s).
Am I adding the glue to the wrong target? Wrong privacies? Wrong linking order? I tried a lot of combinations and variants.

Comment: This feels like building an abstraction over an abstraction over an abstraction over an abstraction. Just use `k_msleep`.

Comment: @KamilCuk except it isn't. The goal is to learn how to build a static library without OS dependencies (I don't want those linked in), so I need the OS glue layer (and the library itself of course)

Comment: You already have OS glue layer - `k_msleep`. And all other Zephyr functions. But ok, one layer is still fine - sometime you need custom functionality. But two? `lib_msleep -> lib_os_msleep -> k_sleep -> actual sleep`? Just `lib_os_msleep` then.

Comment: That's just the OS, not a glue layer. Suppose I want to create a complex library (so not including it as source) that uses many different OS calls, I will need that glue layer (otherwise it's not re-usable), and it will need to be linked into the library for the different projects on different architectures so that it works on those.

Answer (score 2):

`lib_os_msleep` is defined in `lib_os_glue.c`.  (It is also declared in `lib_os_glue.h` and every file that includes that, but that is just a declaration, not a definition.)  If you read your CMafefiles.txt carefully, you can see that you are *not* compiling `lib_os_glue.c` into your `lib` target, but instead you are compiling it into the `app` target.  Therefore, the definition of that function will not get placed into `liblib.a`.  When the linker links your final program, it will need to find the definition of that function elsewhere, since it is not defined in `liblib.a`.  I hope this explains why that function is listed as "undefined" when you inspect `liblib.a`.

It sounds like your program is linking successfully, and I don't understand what your final goal is, so I can't tell you if you should do anything differently.  Maybe everything is fine.  If you want this function to be part of the library, then simply move the file that defines it into the library.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The goal is to learn how to build a static library that needs to use OS calls, but be able to compile it independently. Hence the OS glue layer. In the end I would like to be able to import `liblib.a` and include an OS specific `lib_os_glue.c` in the build, depending on the target OS.

Currently it builds/links successfully, but the `lib_os_msleep()` function is not being called. Which seems odd..

Comment: That is odd.  There is only one definition of `lib_os_msleep` in sight, so if your program links correctly, I would expect all calls to that function to go to the correct definition.  It is totally fine for a static library to reference some external functions.  Maybe your compiler has some weird quirks.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! Thank you David Grayson, you got me in the right direction.

I added one line, to make sure that the application OS glue implementation is linked into the library:
`target_link_libraries(lib PRIVATE app)`

The complete `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20.0)

find_package(Zephyr REQUIRED HINTS $ENV{ZEPHYR_BASE})
project(hello_world)

target_sources(app PRIVATE src/main.c)
target_sources(app PRIVATE src/lib_os_glue.c)

add_library(lib STATIC src/lib/lib.c)
target_include_directories(lib PUBLIC src/lib)

target_link_libraries(lib PRIVATE app)
target_link_libraries(app PRIVATE lib)
```

And I can also use the library as `IMPORTED`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20.0)

find_package(Zephyr REQUIRED HINTS $ENV{ZEPHYR_BASE})
project(hello_world)

target_sources(app PRIVATE src/main.c)
target_sources(app PRIVATE src/lib_os_glue.c)

add_library(lib STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET lib PROPERTY
             IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/lib/liblib.a)
set_property(TARGET lib PROPERTY
             INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/lib)

target_link_libraries(app PUBLIC lib)
```